# An error occurred while saving the attribute set. magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, attribute-set, exception

I am trying to save to attribute in attribute set but getting error like

> An error occurred while saving the attribute set

can anyone help.

In Exception Log file getting below error

> Exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
>   1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO
>   `eav_attribute_label` (`attribute_id`, `store_id`, `value`) VALUES (?,
>   ?, ?)

Answer (score 1):

I got answer for this myself. In database eav attribute tables primary key column was not set for auto_increment attribute. After set the auto_increment problem solved.